0-10V DC output for motorized valve
I have a motorized valve 90 degree with floating type.
I  am trying to build a 0-10V DC output for the same. 
With the angle sensor potentiometer of 10k
Now the point is how to build 0-10V DC output for 90 degree. Kindly advise on what resistors to be added.
The potentiometer travels only 90 degree. But the desired output needed is 0-10V DC

Please list the valve and link to documentation.

You'll need more than resistors. You're only using about 27% of the electrical travel. Maybe something like this (uses the bottom 27% or so of electrical rotation).

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

thank you for the same. will do it and check
